# Snowflake Task dependents

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lets says I have 2 tasks (file_feed_tsk and tbl_merge_tsk) with dependency -
tbl_merge_tsk is scheduled to run after file_feed_tsk completes.

when I run this sql -

```
select * 
from table(information_schema.task_dependents(task_name => 'src_db.src_schema.file_feed_tsk', recursive => true)) ;
```

It displays both the root and child tasks-

```
name, predecessor    

file_feed_tsk,null    
tbl_merge_tsk,file_feed_tsk
```

I copied these 2 rows onto a separate table. Now I need to add a successor to the table. Like,

```
name, predecessor, successor   

file_feed_tsk, null, tbl_merge_tsk    
tbl_merge_tsk, file_feed_tsk, null
```

How do we accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: If successor is always next row in name column, you can just do a ```lead(name)``` to get it.

Comment: or just join the table to itself

Comment: lead() worked. Thanks!